# chdir(variable) in Visual C++ will not accept string variable

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

So Im writing a program that is used to execute other files(exe, bat) in nearby directories.

Please note that i have searched about this a lot, and though i found a few Very similar problems, I am yet to find the solution for this, or at least and alternative approach,..

Im using microsoft visuall c++ 2013 on windows.

Here goes:

```
String ^somedir; 

private: System::Void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) { 
somedir = "0"; //Yes, a folder named 0 in the same directory as this program 
} 
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) { 
_chdir(somedir.c_str()); //Navigate to exe dir, problem is here... 
system("some.exe"); //execute 
_chdir("../"); //go up a level. 
}
```

**BTW im using c++ windows Forms, this is not a console.**

It works perfectly fine if i replace **somedir.c_str()** with a quoted string containing the path, however, im using radio buttons to define the string variable **somedir** as there are multiple directories to execute from.

Why using chdir? Because the executables need to be executed in their own directories where their dependencies exist. I'll be glad to hear there is an alternate method to do this.

The errors i'm getting are:

```
"Error: expression must have a class type."
```

when using **_chdir(somedir.c_str());** and

```
"Error: argument of type 'System::String ^' is incompatible with parameter of type 'const char*' "
```

when using **_chdir(somedir);**

These Errors appear when hovering the cursor over **somedir** inside **_chdir(somedir.c_str());** as it is underlined with a jagged red line, indicating an error.

Forgive me if im doing something stupid, because im really new to C++ and am still learning.

Ill be very exited and happy to hear of different methods of doing this, though I would like to note that my objective is to avoid using multiple overlapping buttons, because i need to keep the code in the minimal size.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using the Microsoft proprietary language called [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is not standard C++ at all?

Comment: I'll be honest, im not completely aware :P, i mean i have coded with both languages but most of what i do is editing and using ideas that i read elsewhere, my background is not very strong but i can understand code.

Comment: Ok, well hopefully you're more aware now. :) Anytime you see a type with `^` in it, that's not standard C++. You might be okay with using C++/CLI, in which case somebody will have an answer for you, but if your intent is to learn standard C++, then you're using the wrong tools (or wrong settings in your tools, as Visual C++ also supports standard C++).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, and honestly, the program i have come to write is all based on research i have done on commands and what they do, i really have no background at all, i can provide the entire code if its necessary.

Comment: I don't know much C++/CLI and I can't find `.c_str()`in the official MS Documentation, however I found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx) by MS where they explain that converting `String` to `char*` should be done via `PtrToStringChars` - maybe it will help?

Comment: @Greg Hwgill could be C++/CX too. Microsoft doesn't make it easy.

Comment: @UnholySheep: Here's `basic_string::c_str()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3372cxcy.aspx

Comment: hm,.. i just tried it, it won't accept it either, because chdir() requires an input of type const char*, while PtrToStringChars() gives type __const_Char_ptr, im really confused as to why there isn't a better function than chdir that can handle better inputs, but then again, what do i know? :P

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: ill try this now,..

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, but unless I misunderstand something `basic_string` is not the same as `String` that is used in this example, and that was what I was referring to. (Unless MS has built in some weird implicit conversion between these two classes, which would be quite confusing to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually very little point to go from a `System::String` to an `std::string` to a `const char*`.  These string type conversions just clog up your code and are very lossy, the latter two types rarely do a good job representing Unicode characters.  You only do this when you absolutely have to, inter-operating with existing native C or C++ code.

You are writing .NET code, use the .NET Framework to accomplish the exact same without the overhead and data loss:

```
   Environment::CurrentDirectory = somedir;
```

Comment: OH DEAR GOD, just when i've been banging my head on my desk for a few days over this simple code, not only do i get a solution i want, but also a much shorter version that does the exact same thing,.. this website is awesome, because of you guys :D

Comment: I made this the answer because it is the correct one, while also being minimalist. However both answers ARE correct and do the same thing, and both of you guys deserve credit for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using C++/CLI there are managed and unmanaged (native) pointers. The managed pointers are the the ones with the caret `^` . C++/CLI is meant as a bridge between managed CLR code and unmanaged C++ so you have to convert from one to the other.

In order to convert the managed String^ pointer to a native C++ pointer you can convert it with something like:

```
System::String ^somedir = "your directory path here";
msclr::interop::marshal_context context; // Create a marshaling context
std::string conv_somedir = context.marshal_as< std::string >(somedir);

// Now use the std::string as you normally would used a standard library string
_chdir(conv_somedir.c_str()); //Navigate to exe dir, This should work now

// Test it
system("dir"); //execute 
_chdir("../"); //go up a level. 
system("dir"); //execute
```

In order to use pointer marshaling you need to also include this at the top:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

You can find more information about `msclr::interop::marshal_as` in this [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx).

> This method is a simplified way to convert data between native and managed types. To determine what data types are supported, see Overview of Marshaling in C++. Some data conversions require a context. You can convert those data types by using the marshal_context Class.

Comment: It seems to want to work, chdir does not have a problem anymore, however this part: msclr::interop::marshal_as now shows and error as follows:Error: no instance of overloaded function "msclr::interop::marshal_as" matches the argument list argument types are: (System::String ^)

Comment: maybe its becuase i defined somedir as String ^somedir; only?

Comment: Oh in your example you may have to prepend the namespace `System` to `String ^` as in `System::String^` . I happened to avoid that issue since I had a namespace specified (I tested the code here and happened to have `using namespace System;` after my includes). I update my answer to align with the code in your question.

Comment: its still giving the same error, even though i am using namespace System, and i even tried appending the definition with System:: anyways, however i get no errors there but still an error with msclr::interop::marshal_as

Comment: i will try to upload a photo of what i have in a sec

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius. a genuine one too :D works like a charm :)
BTW i plan on releasing this to the public soon. You will be credited for your help. You have no idea how much you have helped me, again, thank you very much, and everyone who took the time to try to help :)

Comment: It appears the preferred way is to have a marshaling context. I have amended my answer. Try to make a similar adjustment in your code. So the line with the error should be replaced with these 2 lines `msclr::interop::marshal_context context;` and `std::string conv_realmdir = context.marshal_as< std::string >(realmdir);`

Comment: You don't need to attribute me for help in your code, I was glad to help. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: You need a context to marshal to `char*`, but not when the destination type is RAII, like `std::string`.

Comment: I know @BenVoigt in my code sample it in fact not needed and superfluous(my original answer didn't use it). However, in the actual code the OP is using it was required. I updated my answer so the OP could see how a context could be created. When I have a chance I'll amend my answer to elaborate on when the context is needed.

Comment: man you are so awesome, also for others who might read this, start your executable using Process::Start(); instead of system(); if the executable will stay alive, so that your form won't freeze :D

Comment: @OthmanArnaout: That's a good observation, `system()` specifically waits for the child process to end.  The solution using standard C++ would be `spawn()` and using Windows calls is `CreateProcess()` or `ShellExecute()`.  And, as you noted, `Process::Start()` is the .NET way.